# Last 18 Months data from a Date field of Fact Table: In Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: timestamp, teradata

I have a Date field with data format: 1/20/2014 05:52:05.000000

Now I need to put a WHERE condition in such a way that I can get the last 18 Months data from the Fact table (excluding Current Month).
For example, if I run the table in February (Date field has February data and I don't need this), I should get data from Jan 2015 and 18 month backwards.

What would be the query for this?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Find the first day of the current month using TRUNC and subtract 18 months from it:

```
WHERE ts_col BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'mon'), -18) 
                            AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'mon') -1
```

When you compare a TIMESTAMP and a DATE it's automatically casted to a DATE.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, 
Thanks for this...somehow it didn't worked.... 
I tried by this as well
ROW_UPDATE_STP > add_months(Current_Date, -18)

Now my scene is that if I reload for a Month, I should get data till last day of Previous Month.
For example, I run today (02/05/2015), I should get data till 01/31/2015, not the February Data.
Could you please help in my logic

Comment: Don't use  `CURRENT_DATE`, it's  `TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)`  instead.